# What is a word that means "omen" but for something that has already happened?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, synonyms

Just as the subject says, I'm looking for a noun that is similar in meaning to "omen," but that refers not to something that *will* happen, but rather to something that has *already* happened.

Is there something more precise than "sign?"

> "Lemminkäinen’s mother receives a **___** that her son has been killed, and journeys to the underworld to resurrect him."

Note that the mother is far away from the place of her son's death, and only learns of it through a sign, or a "reverse omen," if you will.

Comment: Could you give an example sentence where this word could be used? Since 'omen' implies foreboding, it really can't apply to the past. So it's unclear how this would be used.

Comment: Exactly. I can't use omen here, so I'm looking for something else. The sentence would be something like: "Lemminkäinen’s mother receives a ___ that her son has been killed, and journeys to the underworld to resurrect him." Note that the mother is far away from the place of her son's death, and only learns of it through a sign, or a "reverse omen," if you will.

Comment: As Jim says, the main defining feature of an omen is that it refers to something in the future. It’s not clear to me what meaning you’re looking for if you take away the central meaning of the word you’re using as your basis. It’s a little bit like asking for an adjective with a similar meaning to _purple_, but without the reference to colour—there isn’t that much left for it to mean, then, unless it’s some specific property of purpleness you’re alluding to.

Comment: @WartimeHotTot  Premonition refers to an intangible sense of something occurring, without a valid & solid reference point it has, or will happen. *"I was on my way to the office and had premonition that I should go the back roads instead of the highway. When I got to work, I found out the highway was closed down by a multi-car accident 15 minutes after I left my house."*

Comment: Do you mean, for example, "This fossil is a ______ that dinosaurs existed here long ago"?

Comment: I think omen is forward-looking relative to the object of the omen, but just because it happened in the past wouldn't mean it is no longer an omen. "I saw a raven on the stop sign, so I stopped. Just then, a car careened through the intersection where I would have been." That raven could be said to be an omen no matter if it all happened in the past. It wouldn't stop being an omen just because the signal and event were both in the past.

Comment: From the sentence you provided, something like "vision".

Comment: @JasonBassford, I don't think this would work, because in the example sentence, the event had already happened when she received the sign.

Comment: @JasonBassford, I don't think this would work, because in the example sentence, the event had already happened when she received the sign.

GEdgar, the sentence you gave is not the spirit of what I'm looking for. It's too concrete. The fossils are facts, pieces of the dinosaurs themselves. The sense I'm looking for is more magical.

Andrew, postmonition is exactly the meaning I'm looking for, but unfortunately this isn't a real word. I can't find it referenced anywhere more reliable than urbandictionary.com. However, "monition" might just work. Thanks, everyone!

Comment: When a word request attracts a long list of ideas, that is a clear signal that either the criteria are unclear or the question is being taken as more of a poll or request for a list of things, neither of which are a good fit for the Stack Exchange model. The word request must be narrow and specific enough that it has one clearly correct answer. It must for example identify the desired connotation, register, and part of speech, and the context in which the word is to be used.

Comment: @Andrew The point isn't that it happens in the past, but rather the order in which the omen and the event happen. Normally, the omen comes *before* the event. The OP is looking for a word indicating an "omen" that comes *after* that event. In your example, it would mean seeing the raven *after* stopping and seeing the car.

Comment: @FabioTurati yes. I realized that after he edited the question. That comment was to the original explanation.

Answer (score 7):

Based on the sentence you provided:

[Vision](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/vision)

> an experience of seeing someone or something in a dream or trance, or as a supernatural apparition.

Postmonition (formed by post- "after in time" and [monition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/monition) meaning "warning" as opposed to a premonition - future) - not a dictonary word.

> dreaming something happened, after it happened, without knowing it happened.

Comment: Yes, I think *vision* or *sign* will have to do. Or the sentence could be recast, *mother somehow knew or felt that her son had been killed*.

Comment: You need to add a reference to your quotations. Which sources are you quoting ?

Comment: Can you please provide source for Postmonition?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend the word "Revelation".

Comment: I was coming to add this word as answer. Can you please flesh out the answer to provide support for why this word works? (definition, explanation, etc)

Answer (score 0):

I am still not clear that the person who received such ***omen*** is a clairvoyant or just a normal person without any supernatural power? Also, the word omen is neutral. There can be good omen or bad omen. But, it can be inferred from the example sentence, that it is a bad omen.

If a person is clairvoyant, then **clairvoyance** (noun) is the word OP is looking for. Clairvoyance is the ability or natural gift that can help you look into the future as well as **past**.

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/clairvoyance

> the power or faculty of discerning objects not present to the senses **or** ability to perceive matters beyond the range of ordinary perception.

E.g.

> People who claim to have clairvoyance are sometimes asked to help locate missing persons.

In above example, people who are clairvoyant can locate already missing person. It clearly indicates, that the event of a person missing already happened in the past.

On the other hand, if a person do not have any special supernatural ability, then I will call such a bad omen as **a whisper in the heart**.

Comment: The question asks for a word that "refers... to something that has _already_ happened." Possibly misread?

Comment: @tmgr thanks! you are right. I completely missed the **past** thingy. Now, I am more confuse about what OP is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You might recast the sentence using [***feeling***](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/I+just+have+this+feeling) along the lines of

> "Lemminkäinen’s mother ***had an*** *uneasy/nasty/distressing/alarming/enraging* ***feeling*** that her son has been killed..."

You can *have a feeling* that something ***has*** happened (in the past), something ***is*** happening (now), or something ***is going to*** happen (in the future).

Answer (score -3):

Intuition might be a possibility. It really depends on how she is receiving the message. The mother's intuition told her...

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage.  We like to see answers with solid explanations and authoritative references.  Perhaps you could edit your answer to provide more detail and some links to support it?  Also, you might want to [take the site tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and read through [the help center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: I would add that the verb form "intuit" is a not-as-common but still recognizable usage.